# Evitar la ejecuccion de un event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Tengo un Formulario que valida un submit en wordpress.
El Siguiente codigo se encuentra en una Plantilla Wordpress y deseo que no se ejecute el event Listener Submit, como puedo evitar que se ejecute?
Para explicarme mejor, cuando se hace click en el button type submit, el formularioo no envia nada, no realiza el proceso del submit.

este es el link donde esta el form: https://amablesbus.com/?p=1074

```
n.on("submit", function (t) {
                if (t.preventDefault(), !0 === a.form_submitting) return !1;
                a.form_submitting = !0;
                var i = e(this),
                    n = i.find(".zn_contact_ajax_response:eq(0)"),
                    o = !1,
                    s = {
                        fields: i.find('textarea, select, input[type="text"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="hidden"]')
                    },
                    r = n.attr("id"),
                    l = i.find(".zn_contact_submit");
                if ((f || u || p) && i.is('[action="#"]') && i.attr("action", ""), l.addClass("zn_form_loading"), s.fields.each(function () {
                        var t = e(this),
                            a = t.parent();
                        t.is(":checkbox") && (t.is(":checked") ? t.val(!0) : t.val("")), a.removeClass("zn_field_not_valid"), t.hasClass("zn_validate_not_empty") ? t.is(":checkbox") ? t.is(":checked") || (a.addClass("zn_field_not_valid"), o = !0) : "" === t.val() && (a.addClass("zn_field_not_valid"), o = !0) : t.hasClass("zn_validate_is_email") ? t.val().match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/) || (a.addClass("zn_field_not_valid"), o = !0) : t.hasClass("zn_validate_is_letters_ws") ? t.val().match(/[^A-Za-z\s]/i) && (a.addClass("zn_field_not_valid"), o = !0) : t.hasClass("zn_validate_is_numeric") && isNaN(t.val()) && (a.addClass("zn_field_not_valid"), o = !0)
                    }), o) return l.removeClass("zn_form_loading"), a.form_submitting = !1, !1;
                var d = i.serialize();
                return e.post(i.attr("action"), d).success(function (t) {
                    a.form_submitting = !1, l.removeClass("zn_form_loading");
                    var n = e(t).find("#" + r + " > .zn_cf_response"),
                        o = e("#" + r),
                        d = i.data("redirect");
                    o.html(n), n.hasClass("alert-success") && (s.fields.val(""), d && window.location.replace(d))
                }).error(function () {
                    console.log("Error loading page")
                }), !1
            })
```

Comment: Podrías clonar el formulario (cloneNode), eliminar el original (removeChild) que se lleva todos sus listeners, y luego el clon lo insertas en el parentNode original que alojaba al formulario eliminado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar quitando todos los event handler (submit) de ese elemento usando el método [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) de jQuery:

```
n.off('submit', '**');
```

Donde "n" es el formulario. Va otro ejemplo:

```
$('form').off('submit', '**');
```

Comment: Funciono a la perfección, mucha gracias, me ayudaste mucho.